# How to close and exit a QDialog shown with exec() after a timeout?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to close a QDialog using a timeout from a QTimer.

So far, i have tried to do this :

```
QDialog dlg;
.. 
..
myTimer.start(60000); // 60 s
connect(&myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()),
        &dlg, SLOT(close())));

dlg.exec();
qWarning() << "---timer expired or key pressed--";
```

But when timeout is triggered and the `close` slot executed the eventloop is not exited. Same behavior with `reject` slot. I know the `done` slot should have the expected behavior but as it needs an extra argument (`int r`), it cannot be directly connected to the `timeout()` signal.

Of course, i can "relay" the `timeout` signal to provide the missing argument but is there another more straightforward way to do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: what about using done() as the slot: "Closes the dialog and sets its result code to r. If this dialog is shown with exec(), done() causes the local event loop to finish, and exec() to return r."

Comment: Create your dialog from heap and don't block the event loop with `dlg->exec()`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the eventloop is not exited'? The dialog did not close?

Comment: Yes dialog is not closed and eventloop not exited. But the real code is more complex and i suspect that all signals and slots with the QDialog are disconnected on the timeout ( signal connected to multiple slots) so that the `close` slot is probably never called.

Answer (score 2):

dlg.exec(); Is a synchronic, He returns the answer accepted or rejected.

```
void MainWindow::btnClicked() {
    Dialog *dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.exec();
    qDebug() << "test"; 
    // while dialog not destroyed (rejected, accepted) Print will not happen never. 
}
```

One way you can use QTimer in your Dialog class:

```
Dialog::dialog(...) {
    //constructor
    QTimer::singleShot(60000, this, SLOT(close()));
}
```

or do not use dialog.exec(); use dialog.show(); if you want dialog let it be modality you can use:

```
void MainWindow::btnClicked() {
    Dialog *dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog->setModal(true);
    dialog->show();
    qDebug() << "test"; //The "test" will be printed, and you can use QTimer :))
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to give the dialog its own timer (i.e. instantiate a QTimer locally, before excuting the dialog):

```
QTimer dlg_timer;
dlg_timer.start(60000); // 60 s
connect(&dlg_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &dlg, SLOT(close()));
dlg.exec();
dlg_timer.stop();
```

As the OP fears in their comment, if the timer timeout signal has been connected to some other slot, before connection with dialog close, and in that slot `QTimer::disconnect()` is called, the dialog close slot will never be called.